# writing to a tab-delimited file or a csv file

Tags: r, export, csv

I have a RMA normalized data ( from the CEL files ) and would like to write it into a file that I could open in excel but have some problems.

```
library(affy)
cel <- ReadAffy()
pre<-rma(cel)
write.table(pre, file="norm.txt", sep="\t")
write.table(pre, file="norma.txt")
```

The outut is arranged row-wise in the text file that is written using the above command and hence when exported to excel it is in a wrong form and many of the information is cut off as the maximum rows are used up .The output looks the following way :

```
GSM 133971.CEL 5.85302 3.54678 6.57648 9.45634
GSM 133972.CEL 4.65784 3.64578 3.54213 7.89566
GSM 133973.CEL 6.78543 3.54623 2.54345 7.89767
```

How to write it in a proper format from CEL files in R to a notepad or  excel ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract the values from the normalised probes using the `exprs` function. Something like:

```
write.csv(exprs(pre), file="output.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear about what the problem is, what do you mean by "proper format"? Excel will struggle with huge tables and doing your analysis in R with Bioconductor is likely a better way to go, you could then export a smaller results or summary table to excel.

Nevertheless, if you want the file written columnwise, you could try:

```
write.csv(t(pre),file="norm.txt")
```

But excel (at least used to) allow many more rows than columns.

Comment: This does not work because "pre" is a RMA normalized CEL files and not a matrix.

Comment: library(affy)
cel <- ReadAffy()
pre<-rma(cel)
ev <- exprs(pre)
write.csv(ev, file="norm.csv") This worked perfectly.

Comment: Right I see, that makes sense. Presumably you could also have used: `write.exprs(pre, file="norm.txt")`